# Find and hide elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, each

How can I use the IDs array to check and hide `#volume2` in the example below?

```
<tr id="mytr">

 <th id="volume1">1</th>
 <th id="volume2">2</th>
 <th id="volume3">3</th>

</tr>

<tr>

 <th class="volume1">1</th>
 <th class="volume2"></th> <-- this is empty
 <th class="volume3">3</th>

</tr>

var IDs = [];
$("tr#mytr").find("th").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
```

I don't want to do all these if statements

```
if( $('.volume1').length < 1 ) {
$('#volume1').addClass('hide');
}

if( $('.volume2').length < 1 ) {
$('#volume2').addClass('hide');
}

if( $('.volume3').length < 1 ) {
$('#volume3').addClass('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many non-empty elements of that class exist. If there are only emepty elements with that class (no non-empty elements), add the "hide" class:

```
$('#mytr').find('th[id]').addClass(function() {
    return $('.' + this.id + ':not(:empty)').length === 0 ? 'hide' : '';
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

As alternative, you could explicitly test whether the cells have content or not:

```
return $('.' + this.id).filter(function() { 
    return $.trim($(this).text()) !==  '';
}).length === 0;
```

This would also consider cells with only whitespace characters as empty.

Comment: Thank you. And what if `<th class="volume2"></th>` would not exist at all? I can still use the .length === 0 right?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$("tr").find("th").each(function(){
    if( $('.' + this.id).length < 1 ) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('table tr:nth-child(2) th').each(function () {
        if (!$.trim($(this).text())) {
            $('#' + this.className).hide();
            $(this).hide()
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BcGPQ/)